# Автопринятие ключей на Salt master

Tags: saltstack

При первоначальном соединении Salt minion отправляет свой открытый ключ.Этот ключ должен быть принят на Salt master. Необходимо что бы ключ принимался сразу как только поступит запрос, но при этом что бы не примал левые ключи от неизвестных миньенов. Предполагаю что нужна некая двухсторонняя авторизация но как именно это сделать не знаю.

Comment: добавьте ключи в master, а потом уже создавайте minion-ов с этими ключами. https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/preseed_key.html

Comment: Спасибо за совет aleksandr буду пробовать. Не знал о таком методе хотя в документацию читал прежде чем задать вопрос.